# How to write in an existing CSV file with data from another csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, csv, read.csv

Just a bit of context: I have two CSV files:

The first one which I will call the **Statement**

The second one the **Big File**

The **Big File** contains a lot of data including `Order ID` numbers that are in the **Statement**.

What I want to do is:

If the `Order ID` from the **Statement** matches the `Order ID` from the **Big File**, then write in **Big File** in the column `Paid`, at the row that contains the `Order ID`, **`"Yes"`**.

So what I wrote was:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = pd.read_csv('Big_File.csv')
data2 = pd.read_csv('Statement.csv')

df = pd.DataFrame(data1)

for i in range(len(data1['PO'])):
    for j in range(len(data2['PO'])):

        if data2['PO'][j] == data1['PO'][i]:

            data1['Supplier'][i] = 'SUP'

            data1['Paid'][i] = 'yes'
```

When I run the code, no error, but then I open the **Big File** to check if it worked and nothing changed.

I am new to writing and reading files in Python, can anyone give me some advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you changed in dataframe not in csv. write your result dataframe to csv file

Answer (score 1):

You still need to output the changes back into the CSV files.

What you've done so far is to read the data from the CSV files into dataframes in Python, located in memory. Then you change them up. But then you stopped. After your for loop, you should then output the changed `data1` back to CSV. For example:

```
data1.to_csv('Big_File.csv')
```

Here are the docs on `to_csv`
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html